Is it possible to make a light follow a non-geodesic path?
I just stumbled upon this question.
For massive particles like an electron, it is easy to make them follow a non-geodesic path by applying an external force. In case of the electron, one can put it under some electric field so it undergoes accelerated motion.
I wonder if it is possible to make massless particles like photons follow a non-geodesic path. I think the simplest way is to send a light beam into a diamond. Will it work?

Use a prism? Or a lens?

Wouldn't the photon still be following a geodesic after it passed through a lens or bounced off a mirror?

@KDP Well, yes, but it would be another geodesic, so in the middle, it couldn't have been on one.

@ChemiCalChems in the middle, there is no photon.

In a medium with a gradient in the RI, the light will follow a non-straight path. This is, for example, what causes a mirage.

The path though a lens is still "geodesic" in the sense that it locally minimizes travel time. But it is not a geodesic in the general-relativity sense.

Arguably an issue with this question is that as far as I know, in the GR formalism we can only make statements about the trajectory of "light" in general, not really about what individual photons do.

In GR we've always been considering free falling objects and thus they travel with geodesics, so I'm thinking here the question is equivalent to asking whether there is a non-gravitational way in which this "free falling" property of photon can be canceled.

A diamond would be very expensive. A mirror would be cheaper solution.

This may well be correct, and the amusing note about the diamond justified, but it's a pity you didn't find it appropriate to explain also why such a path won't be considered a geodesic.

I think, yes, it is possible to influence the geodesic path of a photon. And if I have understood the question correctly, then preferably without reflection on or absorption/re-emission in a material medium.
Since the photon is simultaneously an electric and a magnetic dipole and these fields periodically change their orientation, it would make sense to use an external E or B field to exert an influence. This field would have to oscillate just as quickly as the frequency of the photon. Then we could achieve an attractive effect. Technically, however, we do not have this possibility.
The solution lies where Michael Faraday already experimented, the polarization of light in a magnetic field - it also works with an electric field. If I set up helically aligned magnetic fields along the geodesic path of the light, then I rotate the direction of polarization of the photon continuously. This should not only make it possible to deviate from the path, but also to split out light of different wavelengths.
